# show specific file from the directory in php

Tags: php, html

How can I show a specific file from the directory which name is known to me? I have this code to show all files present in that directory:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo '<div id="imagelist">';
 echo '<p><img src="'.$row['location'].'"></p>';
 echo '<p id="name">'.$row['caption'].' </p>';
 echo '</div>';
}
```

Photos table has 3 columns id, location, caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of the file, you could use

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE caption LIKE '".$name."'");
```

If you know the id of the file it would be better to use that as selecting using an integer is generally faster than selecting on a string.

Note that `mysql_query` is depreceated in PHP now, and you really should be using mysqli_query. Take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: if i have a 

    <input name="caption" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
then how can i assign this filed to $name?

Comment: `$name = $_POST['caption'];`. Or just use `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE caption LIKE '".$_POST['caption']."'");` Assuming your form action is "post". Once you get this working, read up about SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Are you really not going to mention the avoidance of mysql_*?

Comment: @Grim Thank you for the help problem has been solved through your help.